# QGIS Atlas Feature for multiple polygons with same attribute

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, atlas, mapping, atlas-generator

I have a shapefile of city blocks in a given city. Each polygon represents an individual lot, but the attribute table includes a column called "sector", that denotes the zone of the city that the lots are in. There are multiple lots per sector, shown in different colors in picture below:

[image]

I would like to automate the generation of a map of the city blocks for each sector. It appears that the Atlas feature will do what I want, but from what I gather the Atlas feature will create a map for each polygon. How do I have the Atlas produce a map for all polygons that share the same attribute together, instead of individually?

Comment: Create a new layer using a union of lots, using sector to join them

Comment: It looks like you already have a layer for the sectors (black outlines on the map). Use the sector layer to control the atlas, instead of the city blocks layer.

Comment: The answer to this question is that you can't. Both QGIS Atlases and Reports depend on the geometries of individual features to "move" the map window around. So the solutions in the other comments ("create a new layer using the union of the lots" and "Use the sector layer" are correct. If you do not want to show the sectors, you don't need to include them in your map (and for Atlas, you can even use "Hidden layer").